# Adding a categorical color to plot_ly markers invert the size of the points displayed

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm trying to make a plot with `plotly` that have colors representing some class (factor `ff` in my example) and the size representing the population size (column `ss` in my example).  Plotting with a constant color makes the graph ok, i.e. the size of the dots are representative.  However, if I add the `color=~ff` argument to the call, the sizes displayed change and seems inverted!

Here is a RE:

```
# preparing the session and data:
library(plotly)
dd <- data.frame(
  xx = rnorm(10),
  yy = rnorm(10),
  ff = as.factor(c("a","b","c","a","b","c","a","a","b","c")),
  ss = round(runif(10, 100,1000))
)
```

The first plot with no color argument:

```
pp1 <- plot_ly(data = dd,
              x = ~xx,
              y = ~yy,
              marker = list(sizeref = mean(dd$ss)/25,
                            size= ~ss ,
                            sizemode= "diameter",
                            mode = "markers")
              ) 
add_markers(pp1,mode = "markers")
```

*Note: the way I set `sizeref` may look weird but it's the only way I found to make my size pretty in my real code were population size varies greatly. I dough that this causes my problem but it may so I decide to keep it in my example*

This gives:
[image]

Now when I add the `color` argument:

```
pp2 <- plot_ly(data = dd,
              x = ~xx,
              y = ~yy,
              color = ~ff,  ####  !!!  The only line difference
              marker = list(sizeref = mean(dd$ss)/25,
                            size= ~ss ,
                            sizemode= "diameter",
                            mode = "markers")
) 
add_markers(pp2,mode = "markers")
```

gives:

[image]

The colors are ok but the sizes changed and seems inverted.

Any idea what I did wrong?  Could it be that the `sizeref` argument is then applied by category `ff`?  If yes, how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you set your sizeref, but have you tried this:

```
plot_ly(data = dd, x = ~xx, y = ~yy, color = ~ff, size= ~ss) %>% 
add_markers(marker = list(sizeref = 3, sizemode= "diameter"))
```

Comment: It works, thanks.  It doesn't explain why it was inverting the sizes of the markers, but at least I can go forward now.

Comment: Finally, your fix works only partly.  In this example it works, but It doesn't fix it in my actual data which have one tiny observation from a different class. (adding 
 `dd <- rbind(dd, data.frame(xx=-.5, yy=1.5, ff="d", ss=100))`).  I'll see what I can do and I may ask a follow up question.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: funny but it works if you add a second d, dd <- rbind(dd, data.frame(xx=-.5, yy=1.5, ff="d", ss=800))

Comment: Seems like a bug (https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1198), I'll double the points to fix the problem (put two identical points one on top of the other).  It may not be elegant, but it should fix my problem.